# My SQL query doesn't work + insert an image in MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, image, pdo, mariadb

I have 2 problems, my first problem is that I have an error with my PHP script. It basically give me this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in /customers/1/d/9/the-scientist.fr/httpd.www/api/addPost.php:30 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /customers/1/d/9/the-scientist.fr/httpd.www/api/addPost.php on line 30
```

And my second problem is that I'm trying to insert an image in a row in MariaDB, I want to do the same thing as PHPMyAdmin for the image insertion in a BLOB row. So, this is my PHP script:

```
<?php
try
{
   $db = new PDO('mysql:host=the-scientist.fr.mysql;dbname=the_scientist_fr_appli_posts;charset=utf8', 'the_scientist_fr_appli_posts', 'arthur2205');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
   die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
// $security = new White\Security;

$post = $_POST;
$img = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']));
$title = addslashes($post['title']);
$description = addslashes($post['description']);
$fullDesc = addslashes($post['full']);
// if (!empty($title) & !empty($description) & !empty($fullDesc) & !empty($img)) {

// }
// else {
//  // header("Location: form.php?error=Fill the form!");
// }

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (title, description, img, fullDesc, likes) VALUES (:title, :description, :img, :fullDesc, :likes)");

$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
$stmt->bindParam(':description', $description);
$stmt->bindParam(':img', $img);
$stmt->bindParam(':fullDesc', $fullDesc);
$stmt->bindParam(':likes', 0);

$stmt->execute();

    // header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Location: form.php?error=$sql");
```

Also, this is the form:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.2/css/ionic.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form" id="form" action="./addPost.php" method="POST">
         <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Titre" class="AddPosttitle" name="title">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <input class="description" type="text" placeholder="Mot Clés" maxlength="60" name="description">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <div>
                <span id='button_upload'>Image : </span>
                <input type='file' class="img" name="img">
            </div>
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <textarea placeholder="Description" class="full" name="full"></textarea>
          </label>
            <div class="padding">
              <button class="button button-block button-positive submit-btn" type="submit">
               Envoyer
            </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <style type="text/css">
        .form {
            background: #FFF;

        }
    </style>
    <?php
    if (!empty($_GET['error'])){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
                var result = null,
                    tmp = [];
                var items = location.search.substr(1).split("&");
                for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
                    tmp = items[index].split("=");
                    if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
                }
                return result;
            }
            alert(findGetParameter("error"));
        </script><?php
    }
    ?>
```

I think that at this point, my problem is pretty clear, if you need more informations, ask in the comment section .

Comment: i dont know if this is an online testing problem. but you should consider not putting the legit PDO connection to a database here. (if this is the legit connection)

Comment: About your second problem: You have just stated what you want to do and the code you are using, but not what the problem is. Does the insert not work, is the data not what you expect, etc.?

Comment: @B.Dionys Don't worry, I know what I'm doing, you can only access the MariaDB server from my server.

Comment: Ok it was just a question to be sure hihi some people do actually post those connections here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the first problem: You are using:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':likes', 0);
```

[`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) expects a parameter, a variable.

If you just want to bind a value, you should use [`bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) instead:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':likes', 0);
```